# actionFunction doesn't work when not using all the parameters

Tags: actionfunction, ajax, parameters

I'm using the actionFunction to call a method to create payments from my visualforce page.
The thing that changes is the payment type (sometimes its cash sometimes its check and sometimes both).
The problem occurs when i try any type of payment that is not both cash and check (meaning i don't use all the parameters)

my actionFunction:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!createPayments}" name="finishPaymentActionFunction" reRender="showstate">
    <apex:param id="cashAmount" name="cashAmount" value="" />
    <apex:param id="checkAmount" name="checkAmount" value="" />
    <apex:param id="bankParam" name="bankParam" value="" />
    <apex:param id="branchParam" name="branchParam" value="" />
    <apex:param id="serialParam" name="serialParam" value="" />
    <apex:param id="checkDateParam" name="checkDateParam" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

my javascript function:

```
function validatePayment() {
    var cashAmountField = parseFloat($('#cashAmountField').val());
    var checkAmountField = parseFloat($('#checkAmountField').val());
    var checkBankField = $('#checkBank').val();
    var checkBranchField = $('#checkBranch').val();
    var checkSerialField = $('#checkSerial').val();
    var checkDateField = $('#checkDate').val();

    finishPaymentActionFunction(cashAmountField, 
                                checkAmountField,
                                checkBankField,
                                checkBranchField,
                                checkSerialField,
                                checkDateField);
    return true;
}
```

The createPayments method has a debug message at the beginning of it so i know when it is getting called. It only gets logged when i have all parameters with values, if i call the method with any of the parameters empty it doesn't log (meaning it doesn't get called).
What am i missing?

Comment: It seems there is some issue in the calling of the JavaScript function created by apex:actionFunction. Please check if you are getting any JavaScript error in the browser console.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed an issue in the javascript, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was a section in the javascript that i did not include which was returning false causing the method to not be called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the parameter, assignTo="{!nameOfVariableInApexClass}", to pass the value from visualforce page to Apex class.